# Returning multiple result sets via a single database invocation in MSSQL - Hibernate, JPA, JDBC

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am using `EntityManager` `createStoredProcedureQuery` method to call a MSSQL server stored procedure. I was able to use it successfully for procs that return a single resultset. For procs that return multiple resultset, I am only able to retrieve(and map it to my entity class) the first resultset. The stored proc is currently used by our legacy app and I want to reuse it so I don't have to make multiple db calls. The `createStoredProcedureQuery` has an overloaded method (`createStoredProcedureQuery(String var1, Class... var2)`) that takes an array of classes. These classes can be use to map the resultsets to entity classes. But so far it has not been working for me. I believe this works for Oracle stored procs that returns the `REF_CURSOR` but does not work for MSSQL. Does not anybody had a work around for retrieving multiple resultsets in MSSQL using Hibernate, JPA or JDBC?

I think there is a bug/feature that was submitted for this - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9912

This is similar issue I had:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10616

Update 1: Added code below

```
public class MyProcRepository {

    @Autowired  private  EntityManager em;

    public <T> List<T> getMultipleResultset() {
        StoredProcedureQuery spq = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("procWithMultipleResults", AResult.class, BResult.class);
        return spq.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Udpate 2: added this test method

```
    public void getMultipleResultset() {
        StoredProcedureQuery spq = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("procWithMultipleResults");
        List results1 = spq.getResultList(); // this returns null
        if (spq.hasMoreResults()) // this returns false
        {
            List results2 = spq.getResultList(); // get the second result set
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not post code of HOW you are trying to retrieve multiple result sets using JPA `StoredProcedureQuery` ?

Comment: @DN1 updated with sample code

Comment: But that just gets one result set. Tried something like this ? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#_generalised_execution_for_multiple_result_sets

Comment: i came across that before posting the question here in SO but i went ahead and started something new but still not able to retrieve the multiple results. `boolean isResultSet = spq.execute();` return `false` and `spq.hasMoreResults()` always return `false`.

Comment: so there are no more results. You can easily test whether the stored proc is complying with JDBC by just writing the equivalent access via JDBC stored proc API (since that is all that your JPA provider should do).

Comment: `spq.hasMoreResults()` just return false. i think the issue is isolated with mssql. most of the examples out there are either oracle or mysql.

Comment: and as said, you can check that by putting some simple JDBC code together that demonstrates it, so it points the finger at the SQLServer JDBC driver if indeed JDBC shows the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163278/discussion-between-alltej-and-dn1).

Comment: @DN1 this is similiar issue i had - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10616

Comment: Using JdbcTemplate with CallableStatement, I am able to retrieve the multiple resultsets.

Comment: No idea what a "JdbcTemplate" is, and it certainly isnt the JDBC API, but if that can do it then you raise a bug on your JPA provider, demonstrating how it works with JDBC and how it doesnt work with them

Comment: @alltej can you please post your solution based on JdbcTemplate as an answer (and accept it)?

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` is a springframework module.

Comment: @JensSchauder Will post code in next few days.